# My C program will only read the first line of my file

Tags: c, file-io, fgets

So I am trying to read in book information to store, I have the parts to parse through my char array and store in information properly done, but I can only ever read the first line of the files.

I have this separated into two parts(for this), input.c is what handles actually getting and returning the line, and catalog.c is where the file was opened and is what calls the input function.  And I do not have access to getLine on my machine.

catalog

```
void readInBooks(Catalog *cat, char const *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid file: %s\n", filename);
        exit( 21 );
    }

    // This is has been updated to the correct working version!
    char *line;
    
    // Thank you Jabberwocky!!
    while ((line = readLine(fp)) != NULL) {

        // This is where all of the parsing goes
        printf("Line: %s", line);
    }
    fclose( fp );
}
```

input

```
char *readLine( FILE *fp )
{
    char *line;
    line = malloc(sizeof(char) * 512);

    if (fgets(line, BUFFER, fp) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return line;
    }
}
```

And here is an the text file I was trying to read in, it might be worth noting that this program should be able to handle multiple file input one after the other.  Also each book with all of its respective information is on its own line, each line ends with a newline character '\n'.
(Copied straight from the text file, this is exactly what I see, sorry about that)

11  Awakened    Cast, Kristin   8.7 26389   Horror

76  Adventures of Huckleberry Finn  Twain, Mark 8.7 111219  Male friendship -- Fiction;Humorous stories;Missouri -- Fiction;Race relations -- Fiction;Bildungsromans;Finn, Huckleberry (Fictitious character) -- Fiction;Fugitive slaves -- Fiction;Mississippi River -- Fiction;Adventure stories;Runaway children -- Fiction;Boys -- Fiction

84  Frankenstein; Or, The Modern Prometheus Shelley, Mary Wollstonecraft    12.6    74959   Monsters -- Fiction;Frankenstein's monster (Fictitious character) -- Fiction;Gothic fiction (Literary genre);Science fiction;Frankenstein, Victor (Fictitious character) -- Fiction;Scientists -- Fiction;Horror tales

1952    The Yellow Wallpaper    Gilman, Charlotte Perkins   7.2 6067    Mentally ill women -- Fiction,Feminist fiction,Psychological fiction,Married women -- Psychology -- Fiction,Sex role -- Fiction

5200    Metamorphosis   Kafka, Franz    13.8    22022   Psychological fiction,Metamorphosis -- Fiction

To further help clarify my problem, when I call:

```
line = readLine(fp);
```

and then print that line it prints out:

11  Awakened    Cast, Kristin   8.7 26389   Horror

multiple times, because it keeps reading the first line of the file over and over again.

And as Jabberwocky said, it segfaults due to a memory leak somewhere in input

Comment: You can detect the EOF with `while (line != NULL)`. You can't apply `strlen()` to a `NULL` pointer. Apart from that, you have not posted the part which processes the input string.

Comment: BTW what is `BUFFER`? You pass that to `fgets()` but don't use it to allocate the memory.

Comment: I am asking questions which could be resolved by posting the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) – complete one-file code that demonstrates the problem. Please read the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is the first line of file less than 10 chars long?  (Assuming `TEN` == 10)  But....don't do it this way.  Just do: `while( (line = readline(fp)) != NULL ) { ...`

Comment: @WeatherVane I excluded the processing part because I don't need help with them, they work fine. As for BUFFER it just = 512 because otherwise it is considered a MagicNumber.  For reproducing it you could simply print the line to stdout, but my problem still stands that it ONLY reads the FIRST line of the file

Comment: Yes, but, there isn't enough information to reproduce the problem, so all readers can do is to clutch at straws. If you don't know what is causing the problem, you don't know what is relevant to post. Please read the links that were given, you haven't even read the "welcome tour" yet.

Comment: @JoshAvery you should format the text file properly, like your code. Right now it's impossible to determine how the file actually looks.

Comment: @JoshAvery also format the output properly, right now it's hard to see how it actually looks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is overly complicated and wrong.

You probably want this:

```
void readInBooks(Catalog *cat, char const *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file: %s\n", filename);
        exit( BAD_INPUT );
    }

    char *line;
    while ((line = readline(fp)) != NULL)
    {
       printf("Line: %s", line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

There maybe more problems elsewhere though.

There are also some problems in `readline`, I let you find out what as an exercise. Hint: it leaks memory.

Comment: Thank you for straightening out my horrid while loop, unfortunately I can't test it quite yet and there seems to be a few more issues with storing the information I parsed from the line.  Also do to this I can't actually find any of the leaks you mentioned in my readLine function which is also concerning.

Comment: @JoshAvery second hint (almost the solution): what exactly happens with `line` if `fgets` returns `NULL`?

Comment: it never gets freed, you are a saint.